# Viewing and using Facebook login user data

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I followed the [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#setup) provided by Facebook to add a "Login with Facebook" button in my app. In order to populate additional view controllers, I will need to pull data from the logged in user such as name and email. However, there does not seem to be a way to access this data.

For reference, the following code is pasted directly from Facebook instructions.

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
loginButton.readPermissions =  @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where is your code to access the data? did you check out the docs and the api reference? there is example code for this. also, read about "declarative fields" in the changelog.

Comment: Yes - the code to access the data is exactly what I am asking about. I found "declarative fields" here, but it doesn't seem to be exactly related: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: there is example code for every api endpoint in the official docs, just check out the api reference. and declarative fields is definitely related, you will only get id and name without declarative fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Custom Facebook Button Then Just Call the Below Code On Button action:

I already checked it and it works fine for me.
See the reference:

```
-(void)FBLogin{
NSMutableDictionary *fbResultData;
fbResultData =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Process error");
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
         NSLog(@"Cancelled");
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Logged in");
         if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
         {
             [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name,age_range,birthday,devices,email,gender,last_name,family,friends,location,picture" parameters:nil]
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                  if (!error) {
                      NSString * accessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];
                      NSLog(@"fetched user:%@ ,%@", result,accessToken);
                      if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                          [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];
                      }
                      if ([result objectForKey:@"gender"]) {
                          [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"gender"] forKey:@"gender"];
                      }
                      if ([result objectForKey:@"name"]) {
                          NSArray *arrName;
                          arrName=[[result objectForKey:@"name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

                          [fbResultData setObject:[arrName objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"];
                      }
                      if ([result objectForKey:@"last_name"]) {
                          [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"last_name"];
                      }
                      if ([result objectForKey:@"id"]) {
                          [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
                      }
                      [fbResultData setObject:accessToken forKey:@"Access Token"]; //m
                      FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                                    initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/picture?type=large&redirect=false"]
                                                    parameters:nil
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                      [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                            id result,
                                                            NSError *error) {
                          if (!error){
                              if ([[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"]) {
                                  [fbResultData setObject:[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"] forKey:@"picture"];
                              }
                              NSLog(@"Final data of FB login********%@",fbResultData);
                          } }];
                  }
                  else {
                      NSLog(@"result: %@",[error description]);
                      UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) message:[error description] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                      UIAlertAction *alertBtnOk=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                                                 {
                                                     [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                 }];
                      [alert addAction:alertBtnOk];
                      [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                  }
              }];
         }
         else{
             [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
         }
     }
 }];}
```

In fbResultData you will get all user data, but don't forget to import these files:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Comment: Awesome - so a custom button is the way to go. Will report back with results soon.

Comment: OK , wait for your answer.

Comment: A quick follow up question - when I checked the "friends" field, the `data` key returned blank. This is what I saw: `friends =     {
        data =         (
        );
        summary =         {
            "total_count" = 640;
        };
    };` I was wondering if additional permissions were needed for "data"

Comment: With user_friends permission you can have access to the list of your friends that also use your app, so if your app is not used by any of your friend, the list will be empty. See user_friends permission reference:                                      https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_friends

Comment: There is minor change in the code, in place of "friends" in FBSDKGraphRequest replace with "invitable_friends".

Comment: Perfect - I also saw the answer below. Thanks for adding this detail!

Answer (score 1):

This code is useful for getting Facebook login user data and his/her friend's list which are not using your app:

```
-(void)FBLogin{
NSMutableDictionary *fbResultData;
fbResultData =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Logged in");
        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
        {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name,age_range,birthday,devices,email,gender,last_name,family,invitable_friends,location,picture" parameters:nil]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSString * accessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];
                     NSLog(@"fetched user:%@ ,%@", result,accessToken);
                     if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                         [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];
                     }
                     if ([result objectForKey:@"gender"]) {
                         [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"gender"] forKey:@"gender"];
                     }
                     if ([result objectForKey:@"name"]) {
                         NSArray *arrName;
                         arrName=[[result objectForKey:@"name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

                         [fbResultData setObject:[arrName objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"];
                     }
                     if ([result objectForKey:@"last_name"]) {
                         [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"last_name"] forKey:@"last_name"];
                     }
                     if ([result objectForKey:@"id"]) {
                         [fbResultData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
                     }
                     [fbResultData setObject:accessToken forKey:@"Access Token"]; //m
                     FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                                   initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/picture?type=large&redirect=false"]
                                                   parameters:nil
                                                   HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                     [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                           id result,
                                                           NSError *error) {
                         if (!error){
                             if ([[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"]) {
                                 [fbResultData setObject:[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"] forKey:@"picture"];
                             }
                             NSLog(@"Final data of FB login********%@",fbResultData);
                         } }];
                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"result: %@",[error description]);
                     UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) message:[error description] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                     UIAlertAction *alertBtnOk=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                                                {
                                                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                }];
                     [alert addAction:alertBtnOk];
                     [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                 }
             }];
        }
        else{
            [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
        }
    }
}];}
```